# How to pivot a table and count through the values?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have 2 columns in a table named measurements: mac_address and space.
Each line shows a mac_address and the place where it has been detected.

It can have repetitions.

What I want to do is to see how many mac_addresses are shared between spaces. 
I try to do something like this:

```
Space 1 | Space 2 | mac_adress
```

column 1 and column 2 contains all the possible combinations of spaces. The mac_adress column contains the sum of all unique shared mac adresses between these 2 spaces.
I have been stuck for a while with this problem. I tried to implement a solution with `GROUP BY and CASE` but it is not similar to the result I want.

Thanks :)

***Note:*** I am using Athena from AWS so I cannot use modules like Pivot

Comment: by 'space' do you mean a room? Or a location? Or a city/an address?

Comment: a room like a shop for exemple :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the results you are looking for the `measurements` table needs to be joined on itself using `mac_address`, and we need to order the spaces so that only one version of a two-space combination is returned.

```
WITH measurements AS (
SELECT 'room1' AS space, 'a1' AS mac_address
UNION
SELECT 'room1' AS space, 'a2' AS mac_address
UNION
SELECT 'room2' AS space, 'a1' AS mac_address
UNION
SELECT 'room3' AS space, 'a1' AS mac_address
UNION
SELECT 'room3' AS space, 'a2' AS mac_address
)

SELECT
  LEAST(m1.space, m2.space) AS space_1,
  GREATEST(m1.space, m2.space) AS space_2,
  COUNT(DISTINCT m1.mac_address) AS mac_addresses
FROM measurements AS m1
  JOIN measurements AS m2 ON m1.mac_address = m2.mac_address
WHERE
  m1.space != m2.space
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

The `measurements` CTE creates creates dummy data similar to how you described your table:

```
| space | mac_address |
|-------|-------------|
| room1 | a1          |
| room1 | a2          |
| room2 | a1          |
| room3 | a1          |
| room3 | a2          |
```

From this data, we can see that the room1/room2 `space` combination only has one unique `mac_address` (`a1`), room1/room3 has two unique combinations (`a1`, `a2`), and room2/room3 has one unique combination (`a1`).

Because we're joining `measurements` on itself, we use `GREATEST` and `LEAST` to ensure that we only count `room1/room2` and not `room2/room1` also.